# MongoDB network subnet lookup for IPV6

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection of documents where each document represents a network subnet for IPV6 as below,

- 2001:0D38:ABCD:0012::0/64

How to identify whether given address (2001:0D38:ABCD:0012:0:0:0:1) belongs to the subnet configured in mongodb ?

Since mongo db does not support big integer data type, i cannot convert IPV6 address to integer and store in DB like IPV4.

Comment: It would significantly simplify the job if you could also store the mask as a pair of min and max addresses.

Comment: yeah.. i can also store mask to find min and max address.. but what kind of binary operation need to perform to check subnet validation ?

Comment: No binary operations I'm afraid. Simple string comparison. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can store min and max address of the subnet within the document as a decimal string, e.g.:

```
{
    mask: '2001:0D38:ABCD:0012::0/64',
    minIP: '42540756323247557835581172037552439296',
    maxIP: '42540756323247557854027916111261990911'
}
```

The query to find all documents that include IP '2001:0D38:ABCD:0012:0:0:0:1' would be as simple as

```
db.collection.find({
    minIP: {$lte: '42540756323247557835581172037552439297'}, 
    maxIP: {$gte: '42540756323247557835581172037552439297'}
})
```

Comment: yeah.. it works. But will there be any performance issue if we do frequent query on subnet validation, since doing comparison ($lte, $gte) operation on a string instead of integer ?

Comment: Index it. It won't be much slower than integers. It will require much more RAM to keep indices though. Test it. **If** it is a problem - update the question with relevant details of the setup.

Comment: yeah.. sure.. Thanks for the solution and suggestion.

Comment: In my case, comparing numbers as strings in MongoDB doesn't work. It doesn't realise they are numbers. For example it states that "11" < "2" which doesn't help me, as it is just the same lexicographical comparison as always.

Comment: @user3289695 very good point. You definitely need leading zeros to make it working.

Comment: How do you convert a IPv6 address to a decimal number? A IPv6 address has 128 bit, so it will be a challenge, because `long` datatype has only 64 bits. Any math operation like `Math.pow` will fail. Maybe it is easier to convert the IPv6 address to a consistent HEX string (i.e. insert missing "0")

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit there are big.js & similar. Node supports bigints natively. IIRC python uses 16 bytes internally, and converts it to string/int by typecasting. hex will do too. Full 0 and allcaps/lowcase should work. You just need to implement it manually. Conversion to integer is standard and I'm sure there are libs in most languages.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about `mongosh` and MongoDB itself which use only Int32, Long (64 bit) and decimal (which has 34 decimal digits but 39 would be required). I come from Oracle where `NUMBER` data type also supports only up to 38 significant digits. If you like to convert it natively in an aggregation pipeline, then you have a challenge.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I see what you mean and had the same concerns, hence I started the answer with "If you can store min and max address of the subnet within the document as a decimal string". Apparently it's not that clear, so let me emphasise the prerequisites - the IP should be stored as a string on mongodb. All IP-to-bigint and bigint-to-string should happen on the client. It should be ok for apps, but indeed can be an issue for db-to-db connectors.

Comment: Did you end up left padding with zeroes to the max number of digits?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78115924/index-large-ip-address-database-in-mongodb-query-is-slow for an aggregate query that will run quickly if you have full IP address database.  But it was for IPV4, and I'm adapting now for IPV6.