# Query/Index Large IP Address Database in MongoDB - query is slow

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I uploaded a purchased IP Address database to MongoDB.
The collection has 26,060,844 rows.
We use the numeric version of the IP Address to lookup a given IP.
So for example, I want to lookup: 1219828147.

We had done something similar two years ago with a similar database, and got it working in 1 or 2 seconds, but nobody remembers how we did it, and that collection and index is gone now.

My theory is that the index should need the start/end long-integers and then the _id to jump to the full data.  I don't think we want to do a covered index with all fields in the index.

What can I change on my index to get this to run in 1-2 seconds?

The following query typically takes 20-35 seconds.

```
db.ipdb.explain("executionStats").find({
    $and: [
      {
        ipDbIpStartInt64: { $lte: 1219828147 }
      },
      {
        ipDbIpEndInt64: { $gte: 1219828147 }
      }
    ]
  })
```

Result of:

```
db.getCollection("ipdb").getIndexes()
```

Note, the two of the fields being indexed are Long Integers.

JSON:

```
[
    {
        "v": NumberInt("2"),
        "key": {
            "_id": NumberInt("1")
        },
        "name": "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v": NumberInt("2"),
        "key": {
            "ipDbIpEndInt64": NumberInt("1"),
            "ipDbIpStartInt64": NumberInt("1"),
            "_id": NumberInt("1")
        },
        "name": "iXIpDb"
    }
]
```

Data returned by the query:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65dce31c8ca603982c60e02f"),
    "ipDbIpStartInt64": NumberLong("1219821568"),
    "ipDbIpEndInt64": NumberLong("1219829759"),
    "ipDbIpStartString": "72.181.0.0",
    "ipDbIpEndString": "72.181.31.255",
    "ipDbContinentCodeString": NaN,
    "ipDbCountryCodeString": "US",
    "ipDbStateProvCodeString": "TX",
    "ipDbStateProvNameString": "Texas",
    "ipDbDistrictNameString": "Dallas",
    "ipDbCityNameString": "Irving",
    "ipDbZipcodeString": "75063",
    "ipDbLatitudeDecimal": NumberDecimal("32.9117"),
    "ipDbLongitudeDecimal": NumberDecimal("-96.9907"),
    "ipDbGeoNameIdInt": NumberInt("4700168"),
    "ipDbTimezoneOffsetDecimal": NumberDecimal("-6"),
    "ipDbTimezoneNameString": "America/Chicago",
    "ipDbWeatherCodeString": "USTX0646",
    "ipDbIspNameString": "Spectrum",
    "ipDbAsNumberDecimal": NumberDecimal("11427"),
    "ipDbUsageTypeString": "cable",
    "ipConnectionTypeString": "cable",
    "ipDbOrganizationNameString": "Road Runner",
    "ipDbIsActive": true,
    "ipDbDateCreated": ISODate("2024-02-26T11:04:34.054Z"),
    "ipDbDateUpdated": ISODate("2024-02-26T11:04:34.054Z"),
    "geoPopulationInt": 236607
}
```

The explain shows this:

```
{
    "explainVersion": "1",
    "queryPlanner": {
        "namespace": "RelatixDB.ipdb",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": {
                        "$lte": 1219828147
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": {
                        "$gte": 1219828147
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "queryHash": "3139F81F",
        "planCacheKey": "0CEDD871",
        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "_id": NumberInt("1")
                },
                "indexName": "iXIpDb",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [ ],
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [ ],
                    "_id": [ ]
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": NumberInt("2"),
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [
                        "[1219828147.0, inf.0]"
                    ],
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [
                        "[-inf.0, 1219828147.0]"
                    ],
                    "_id": [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": [ ]
    },
    "command": {
        "find": "ipdb",
        "filter": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": {
                        "$lte": 1219828147
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": {
                        "$gte": 1219828147
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "$db": "RelatixDB"
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "atlas-bp0ybm-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net",
        "port": NumberInt("27017"),
        "version": "7.0.6",
        "gitVersion": "66cdc1f28172cb33ff68263050d73d4ade73b9a4"
    },
    "serverParameters": {
        "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": NumberInt("0"),
        "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeRestricted"
    },
    "ok": 1,
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": Timestamp(1709741767, 1),
        "signature": {
            "hash": BinData(0, "jLRlCLT72axkhxdRtyZVMw6tUi0="),
            "keyId": NumberLong("7333716473929531397")
        }
    },
    "operationTime": Timestamp(1709741767, 1)
}
```

Part 2 - I tried just projecting the two columns in the index, but the run time was still 29 seconds:

```
db.ipdb.find({
    $and: [
      {
        ipDbIpStartInt64: { $lte: 1219828147 }
      },
      {
        ipDbIpEndInt64: { $gte: 1219828147 }
      }
    ]
  },
    
    { ipDbIpStartInt64: 1,
      ipDbIpEndInt64: 1,
 }
    
)
```

And here is .explain("executionStats"):

```
{
    "explainVersion": "1",
    "queryPlanner": {
        "namespace": "RelatixDB.ipdb",
        "indexFilterSet": false,
        "parsedQuery": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": {
                        "$lte": 3168228785
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": {
                        "$gte": 3168228785
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "queryHash": "3139F81F",
        "planCacheKey": "0CEDD871",
        "maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached": false,
        "maxScansToExplodeReached": false,
        "winningPlan": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "_id": NumberInt("1")
                },
                "indexName": "iXIpDb",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [ ],
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [ ],
                    "_id": [ ]
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": NumberInt("2"),
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [
                        "[-inf.0, 3168228785.0]"
                    ],
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [
                        "[3168228785.0, inf.0]"
                    ],
                    "_id": [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans": [ ]
    },
    "executionStats": {
        "executionSuccess": true,
        "nReturned": NumberInt("1"),
        "executionTimeMillis": NumberInt("39863"),
        "totalKeysExamined": NumberInt("21580909"),
        "totalDocsExamined": NumberInt("1"),
        "executionStages": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "nReturned": NumberInt("1"),
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberInt("6974"),
            "works": NumberInt("21580909"),
            "advanced": NumberInt("1"),
            "needTime": NumberInt("21580907"),
            "needYield": NumberInt("0"),
            "saveState": NumberInt("21580"),
            "restoreState": NumberInt("21580"),
            "isEOF": NumberInt("1"),
            "docsExamined": NumberInt("1"),
            "alreadyHasObj": NumberInt("0"),
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned": NumberInt("1"),
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate": NumberInt("6886"),
                "works": NumberInt("21580909"),
                "advanced": NumberInt("1"),
                "needTime": NumberInt("21580907"),
                "needYield": NumberInt("0"),
                "saveState": NumberInt("21580"),
                "restoreState": NumberInt("21580"),
                "isEOF": NumberInt("1"),
                "keyPattern": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": NumberInt("1"),
                    "_id": NumberInt("1")
                },
                "indexName": "iXIpDb",
                "isMultiKey": false,
                "multiKeyPaths": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [ ],
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [ ],
                    "_id": [ ]
                },
                "isUnique": false,
                "isSparse": false,
                "isPartial": false,
                "indexVersion": NumberInt("2"),
                "direction": "forward",
                "indexBounds": {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": [
                        "[-inf.0, 3168228785.0]"
                    ],
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": [
                        "[3168228785.0, inf.0]"
                    ],
                    "_id": [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined": NumberInt("21580909"),
                "seeks": NumberInt("21580908"),
                "dupsTested": NumberInt("0"),
                "dupsDropped": NumberInt("0")
            }
        }
    },
    "command": {
        "find": "ipdb",
        "filter": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "ipDbIpStartInt64": {
                        "$lte": 3168228785
                    }
                },
                {
                    "ipDbIpEndInt64": {
                        "$gte": 3168228785
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "$db": "RelatixDB"
    },
    "serverInfo": {
        "host": "atlas-bp0ybm-shard-00-02.xxxxx.mongodb.net",
        "port": NumberInt("27017"),
        "version": "7.0.6",
        "gitVersion": "66cdc1f28172cb33ff68263050d73d4ade73b9a4"
    },
    "serverParameters": {
        "internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS": NumberInt("0"),
        "internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes": NumberInt("104857600"),
        "internalQueryFrameworkControl": "trySbeRestricted"
    },
    "ok": 1,
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": Timestamp(1709749633, 12),
        "signature": {
            "hash": BinData(0, "eLH0ZRJQBB7Sw0/uGLMEdXnEiS8="),
            "keyId": NumberLong("7333716473929531397")
        }
    },
    "operationTime": Timestamp(1709749633, 12)
}
```

Comment: I just noticed start and end are backwards in the index.  Maybe that's the issue, I will try to flip it.

Comment: My colleague was unfortunately trying to get it to work and deleted my index and created a new one, ugh.

Comment: Explain will tell you more about the performance of the query if you use "executionStats" or "allPlansExecution".

Comment: @Joe I added that to the post, doesn't it build something like a BTree - and should only do about 8 to 10 IOs to search and find my row?  These seem really high! "keysExamined": NumberInt("21580909"),
                "seeks": NumberInt("21580908"),

Comment: You don't filter on `_id`, so try to create an index on `{ipDbIpEndInt64: 1, ipDbIpEndInt64: 1}`

Comment: Do any of the IP ranges in the database overlap?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - but then how would it jump back to the original full document?

Comment: @Joe No - I thought I made it a unique index.

Comment: re: _id in the index - the underlying storage engine uses a separate internal identifier to link index keys to the source document, you do not have to add _id to get that behavior.

Comment: An index has always an internal reference to the document, otherwise the index would be pointless. You don't have to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the index bounds that were scanned.  In order to find all matching documents, the executor scanned all of the index keys with a `ipDbIpStartInt64` value from negative infinity to  1219828147, and then for each match, a scan for `ipDbIpEndInt64` from 1219828147 to infinity within those results.  You might try inverting the order in one of the fields when building the index, like: `{ipDbIpStartInt64: 1, ipDbIpEndInt64: -1}`, but whether that performs better will likely depend on where the specific value in the query falls within the index keys.

Since you have indicated that the IP ranges will not overlap, an alternate way to query is find the range with the greatest ipDbIpStartInt64 that is less than the queried value, then check the ipDbIpEndInt64 for only that range.  If the ranges don't overlap, either that range contains the queried value, or no range does.

Any index that has ipDbIpStartInt64 as the first field would be able to service this query.

```
db.ipdb.aggregate([
   {$match:{ ipDbIpStartInt64: {$lte: 1219828147}}},
   {$sort:{ ipDbIpStartInt64 : -1 }},
   {$limit: 1},
   {$match:{ ipDbIpEndInt64: {$gte: 1219828147}}}
])
```

This should allow the query executor to:

- scan the  `{"ipDbIpStartInt64": 1, "ipDbIpEndInt64": 1, "_id": 1}` index in reverse order, using index-based sort, no in-memory (any index with ipDbIpStartInt64 as the first key will suffice)
- stop scanning after finding a single match for ipDbIpStartInt64, since the limit will be satisfied
- return that result if ipDbIpEndInt64 also matches, return nothing otherwise

Comment: Wow, you're the "bomb!".  Thanks, I've done IDMS Mainframe DB, and MS/SQL, and MongoDB bites me me all the time.

Comment: I tried my original query with hint("ixipdb_StartInt64Asc_EndInt64Desc"), a new index with Start# ascendi and End# descending.  It ran in 30 seconds, so faster but your answer above was like 0.5 seconds.